# Otto and Retrofit - Register a retrofit service

Tags: retrofit, otto

Most of the examples that I have seen, registers the retrofit service in the Application's oncreate method.

Something like this.

```
class ReaderApplication extends Application {

  private StoryService mStoryService;
  private Bus mBus = BusProvider.getInstance();

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();

  mStoryService = new StoryService(buildApi(), mBus);
  bus.register(mStoryService);

  bus.register(this); //listen for "global" events
  }

 private StoryApi buildApi() {
  return new RestAdapter.Builder()
              .setServer(API_URL)
              .build()
              .create(StoryApi.class);
  }

  @Subscribe
  public void onApiError(ApiErrorEvent event) {
   toast("Something went wrong, please try again.");
   Log.e("ReaderApp", event.getErrorMessage());
  }
}
```

What happen if I have more than one service in the App, I don't think it's a good idea to register all of them in the Application. Can I register the retrofit service in an Activity or Fragment? And what will be the best place to register the service?

Answer (score 0):

You can register anytime you want. Preferably, you can register it in `onResume()` method of a both, `Activity` and `Fragment`. Otto is not coupled to activity/fragment life-cycles. Events are dispatch on the class object.

Comment: But, if I do this "bus.register(mStoryService)" in the "onResume()", I will get a crash saying that the service is already registered